# redirect to page call from server in meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm using iron router and

In the serve I've a http method

in `server/methods.js`

```
  '/fail':function(data){
            console.log("fail");
            console.log(data);
            return "<h5>Your payment is failed.<a href='/'>Click here</a> to go back to site</h5>"
        }
```

when calling this method I don't want to display simple message, I want to redirect to url

How to do this using `iron:router`

I tried using `Router.go` It is saying object has no method `go`

My router code is in

```
lib/router.js
```

**EDIT**

```
https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-http-methods
```

The method above declared is a `http-method` using the above package

I'm using this method on  my server and

I've integrated some api in my application that api sends post request to `/fail` url

this is all working fine and I'm able to process the data also

but after processing the data I want to return to some url.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to do. Router.go is a valid method, can you give us a snippet? Why do you return html markup from a method? One of the meteor principles is to just have data (no markup) on the wire.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the `.go` method only works on a Router instance, not on the Router global object itself, so maybe that is the issue?

Also, it appears that the `.go` function is only available on the client, not on the server. So that might be a thing as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can always fall back to base HTTP.  This is the only method I've found that works.

```
'/fail':function(data){
        console.log("fail");
        console.log(data);
        this.response.statusCode = 302;
        this.response.setHeader('Location', '/');
        this.response.end('See ya');
    }
```